# how to access text field from main class to extended class in java

Tags: java, swing

I have a main class File 
and another extend class File 2

how can i access a textfield declared in File with awt and Swing to the extended class File2 ?

main class:-

```
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FileReceive extends FileReceiveUtil {




    int msgIndex = 1;
    Statement s;
    public static File f;
    public static String phoneNo, phoneNoLo, sk;
    public static String str = "";
    public static String path = "";
    public String ran, ran11;
    public String mes, sharedString;



    FileReceive() throws Exception {
        super("COM4");
    }

    @Override
    public void processSMS(String str) throws Exception {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {




        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Receive");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        JLabel nameId = new JLabel("Enter Destination Path");
        JButton browseb = new JButton("Browse");
        JLabel bodyTempId = new JLabel("Path : ");
        final JTextField jtf = new JTextField(" ");
        JButton sendB = new JButton("Receive");

        panel.add(nameId);
        panel.add(browseb);
        panel.add(bodyTempId);
        panel.add(jtf);
        panel.add(sendB);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        this()


        browseb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
                String str1 = "";
                int m = jf.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (m == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    f = jf.getSelectedFile();
                    str = f.getPath();
                    path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    jtf.setText(path);
                }
            }
        });

        sendB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                FileReceiveUtil util = null;
                try {
                    util = new FileReceive();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileReceive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
                try {
                    util.startReceive(al, 10);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileReceive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Extended class :-

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public abstract class FileReceiveUtil implements Runnable {

    private static int responseCode = -1;
    private static String userCredentials = null;
    private static String cookie = null;
    private static String site = null;
    private static String actionStr = null;
    private Enumeration portList;
    private CommPortIdentifier portId;
    private SerialPort serialPort;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private String strPortName;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private boolean boolKeepReceiving = true;
    private Thread threadRX;
    private ArrayList alSMSStore;
    private int intDelay;

    public FileReceiveUtil(String strPortName) throws Exception {
        this.strPortName = strPortName;
        initCommPort();
    }

    private void initCommPort() throws Exception {
        boolean boolPortOK = false;
        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                if (portId.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(strPortName)) {
                    this.serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(230400,
                            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    boolPortOK = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!boolPortOK) {
            throw new Exception("Port " + strPortName + " does not exist!");
        }
    }

    private String readSMS() throws Exception {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(writeATCmd());
        return sb.toString();
    }



    private String writeATCmd() throws Exception {



        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[1];
       // Thread.sleep(10);
        int ch = inputStream.read(data);

                //System.out.println(x);
            bos.write(data, 0, 1);
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();        
           File someFile = new File("D:\\yadhu.txt");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile,true);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
            String str = bytes.toString();
        System.out.println("Data : "+ str);
        return str;
    }

    private void startReceivingSMS() throws Exception {
        final String ERROR = "ERROR";
        while (boolKeepReceiving) {
            Thread.sleep(intDelay);
            try {
                System.out.println(" File recieved ");







                String str = readSMS();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("ERROR RECEIVING MSG");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    final public void startReceive(ArrayList alSMSStore, int intDelay) throws Exception {
        this.alSMSStore = alSMSStore;
        this.intDelay = intDelay;
        threadRX = new Thread(this);
        threadRX.start();
    }

    final public void run() {
        try {
            startReceivingSMS();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    final public void stopReceivingSMS() {
        this.boolKeepReceiving = false;
    }

    public ArrayList getReceivedMessages() {
        return this.alSMSStore;
    }

    private static void exit(String errorMsg) {
        System.err.println(errorMsg);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public abstract void processSMS(String message) throws Exception;

}
```

i want   `File someFile = new File("D:\\yadhu.txt");`  to change this and add file name from the jtextfield on gui
please help

Comment: Would you share your code? Some context would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

if the attribute in your main class `File` are not private you can access them from the child Class with `this` or `super` keywords.